# two foreach loops with the same variable don't work in html - using twig in slim framework php

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying in my code to build a list of courses in an html file (using twig) - but the thing is - I need to use it twice.
Once to get the list (and that obviously worked), and once to create a form with multiple checkboxes running in another for loop.
I read that the 'unset' function can fix this problem - but it says in doesn't exist in Twig.
here's my code:

```
{% for course in courses %}
   <a href="/course/{{course.id}}">
    <div id="info-box">
    <img src="/views/{{course.image_link}}" alt="" width=95>
    <p style="margin-left: 1rem;">{{course.name}}</p>
    </div>  
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

and then I need to write a form:

```
<form>

    {% for course in courses %}
         <input type="checkbox" name="course" value={{course.id}}>{{course.name}}           
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

The second loop doesn't work.
I'd love for some help please! :)

and the `courses` variable comes from a different index file that sends it to an html file.

Comment: it's not `unset` but `reset($courses)` that could fix the problem - in pure php.

Comment: What kind of type is the variable `courses`?  How did u populate it

Comment: yes but I can only use twig. and 'courses' is an array that arrives from the database - I'll show you:
`$courses = Course::getAll();` 

`return $this->view->render($response, 'course_edit.html', [

  'courses' => $courses,
 ]);`

Comment: that's a var_dump on $courses:
`object(PDOStatement)#91 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(68) " SELECT id, name, description, image_link FROM courses " }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why u only can use `twig` as it would be better to fetch the result in actual array than rather passing the `PDOStatement`.

The reason u can only foreach the collection once is because `PDOStament` is a forward-only result set. This  means you can only get the data from this object once.

To resolve this issue in `twig` this would mean u need to build an array first and then use that array to display your `html`

```
{% set courses_array = [] %}
{% for course in courses %}
    {% set courses_array = courses_array | merge([course]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

It sure is better to do this in `PHP`, rather then in `twig`

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM courses');
    $stmt->execute();

    $courses = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $twig->render('courses.twig', [ 'courses' => $courses, ]);
```

---

Another solution would be to do the fetch inside `twig`, to access a constant you can use the function `constant`

```
{% set courses_array = courses.fetchAll(constant('PDO::FETCH_ASSOC')) %}
```

*note: I did not test the last solution*